# Retrieve a random object from an ArrayList: incompatible types

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a random Base from an ArrayList:
Edit: full code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Random randomGenerator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<Base> baseArrayList = new ArrayList<Base>();
        Base baseOne = new Base("Grüner Salat");
        Base baseTwo = new Base("Gemischter Salat");
        Base baseThree = new Base("Rüeblisalat");
        Base baseFour = new Base("Eisbergsalat");

        baseArrayList.add(baseOne);
        baseArrayList.add(baseTwo);
        baseArrayList.add(baseThree);
        baseArrayList.add(baseFour);

        Button mixSaladBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mixSaladBtn);
        mixSaladBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView baseTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baseTextView);

                String baseDisplay =  getRandomBase(baseArrayList);
                baseTextView.setText(baseDisplay);
            }
        });

        ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredientArrayList = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();

    }

    public String getRandomBase(ArrayList<Base> baseArrayList){
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(baseArrayList.size());
        Base randomBase = baseArrayList.get(index);
        System.out.println(randomBase);
        return randomBase.getIngredientName();
    }
}
```

The App crashes when I call the method getRandomBase in the onClick method. Somehow I'm not getting back a Base from `baseArrayList.get(index);`
Final edit: I had 2 errors. The first one was that at first I used a raw type. Many thanks for the clarifications!
The second error was that I had to move the declaration of the Random randomGenerator();

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**. It should work with `Base randomBase = (Base) baseArrayList.get(index);`. There might be other reason of crash. If you can share the full code we might be able to help you.

Comment: `ArrayList baseArrayList` to `List<Base> baseList `?

Comment: How do you create the list? This code should not compile. You need to provide the type in the signature: `ArrayList<Base> baseArrayList` or cast it.

Comment: Please add the part of the code where you create the list and where you add elements to it

Comment: tried with isInstanceOf? Maybe there are items in that list that are not Base?

Comment: Michael, what do you mean by "the App still crashes"? I assume you've got an error message (called "stack trace"). If you add it to your question, we can probably tell you more.

Comment: **Never use raw types.** You are using `ArrayList`, but it requires a type argument. Change it to `ArrayList<Base>` (or better, `List<Base>`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: May be your app crashes with `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in `baseArrayList.get(index)` when you get random index?

Comment: I'm getting a NullPointerException, not an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @MichaelStotzer Add error trace also

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in the method you are sending raw arraylist . so it doesn't know what data type it is . There are two ways you can fix

**1. Casting**

```
Base randomBase = (Base) baseArrayList.get(index);
```

2. Sending Type in method

   ```
   public String getRandomBase(List<Base> baseArrayList){
   ```

   }

Comment: I tried both:
`public String getRandomBase(ArrayList<Base> baseArrayList){
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(baseArrayList.size());
        Base randomBase = (Base) baseArrayList.get(index);
        System.out.println(randomBase);
        return randomBase.getIngredientName();
    }`
It still crashes.

Comment: just one way enough i would prefer 2 one

Comment: You can update your code with error stack so that we can fix will you ?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
public String getRandomBase(ArrayList<Base> baseArrayList){...
```

Comment: Why should one try that? Please add some explanation to your code, such that others can learn from it